# How to add a row in an existing Excel file using Java?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

How to add a row in an existing Excel file using Java? I tried using this code but it's not 
working. Please tell me what corrections I need to do.

```
try {
  String s1 ,s2,s3,s4;
  s1 = jTextField1.getText();
  s2 = jTextField2.getText();
  s3 = jTextField3.getText();
  s4 = jTextField4.getText();
  FileInputStream fis =  null;
  File excel =  new File ("E:\\two\\record.xlsx");
  fis = new FileInputStream(excel);
  XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
  XSSFSheet ws = wb.getSheet("cmss");
  int rowNum = ws.getLastRowNum() + 1;
  Row row = ws.createRow(4);
  String[] s = new String[4];
  s[0] = s1;
  s[1] = s2;
  s[2] = s3;
  s[3] = s4;
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    Cell cell = row.createCell(i);
    cell.setCellValue(s[i]);
  }
  jTextField1.setText("");
  jTextField2.setText("");
  jTextField3.setText("");
  jTextField4.setText("");
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
  Logger.getLogger(Addxl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (IOException ex) {
  Logger.getLogger(Addxl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-excel-file-apache-poi/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you write the file out after adding rows? For example:

```
wb.write(new FileOutputStream(excel));
```

Comment: i made the change in line Row row = ws.createRow(rowNum); and added your line wb.write(new FileOutputStream(excel)); . and now its working but here i am taking all string values and if i want to submit string as well as integer value then what should i do bcoz currently when i am entering one integer value its showing string in excel..

Comment: Hm, I see you marked my answer. What I mean in my answer is: the change you made just affect the current `XSSFWorkbook` object in the memory. The `XSSFWorkbook` object is not the file, and whatever changes you made will not be written to the file automatically. Instead you have to manually call the `write` method. Hope this help.

Comment: That's a different thing though, I guess you can simply check the first character of the `String` (s1, s2... s4) and then call `Integer.parseInt` if it is a number.